# STS: Serving Web Content with Spring MVC not working

Tags: spring, eclipse, spring-tool-suite

on STS you can import a Spring Getting Started Guide and so I did with "Serving Web Content with Spring MVC now working" (as "complete" not "initial"). Then I start the server in debugging mode, expecting everything to work, but instead I get:

```
HTTP Status 404 – Not Found
Type Status Report

Message /greeting

Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.
```

To me, it seems that everything is ok because the end point is set correctly like the [guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/) explains: `@RequestMapping("/greeting")`

**EDIT 1:**
No errors on any of my consoles when I try to access the end point:
Pivotal tc Server Developer Edition v3.2:

```
mar 07, 2018 10:06:37 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFORMAZIONI: Initialization processed in 2138 ms
mar 07, 2018 10:06:47 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFORMAZIONI: Server startup in 9346 ms
```

AJDT Event trace:

```
10:7:52 Startup information: 
   AJDT version: 2.2.4.201710301818
   AspectJ Compiler version: DEVELOPMENT
   usingVisualiser=true
   usingXref=true
   usingCUprovider=true
   ajde.version.at.previous.startup = 2.2.4.201710301818
```

Java Stack Trace:

```
Paste stack traces into this console and follow hyperlinks to source code.
```

Maven: Empty!

HostOSGi:

```
Paste stack traces into this console and follow hyperlinks to source code.
```

It seems like I am running something different than I expect. My Package-Explorer:
[image: Package-Explorer]

Comment: I imported the "Serving Web Content" guide into a STS 3.9.2 installation and it seems to run fine both in standard as well as in debug mode. Can you take a look at the log output to see if there is an error showing up when you start it in debug mode?

Comment: @MartinLippert thanks for the answer. Please read EDIT 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you try to deploy your Spring Boot app to a locally running tc Server instance of something like that. You don't need to do that. Just open the Boot Dashboard view, select your boot project, and click "(Re)Start".

It starts up with an embedded Tomcat instance, which is the default for Spring Boot and works for all the guides out-of-the-box.

Comment: wow I feel so stupid. The solution to my problem was so trivial. Thanks :)